# Response format differs from request in rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, render

I have template: `blabla.haml`  And 2 layouts:

1. `layouts/application.js.erb`
2. `layouts/application.html.haml`

In controller i have `render 'blabla.haml'` In log: `request.xhr? # true`

So if I send request with ajax I still get html answer: text/html and layouts/application.html.haml as layout

What should I do to get correct js answer?

Comment: do you have a `respond_to` block in controller action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your controller you should have something like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController::Base
  def index
   respond_to do |format|
    format.js { }
    format.html {}
   end
  end
 end
```

you could as well implement it with respond_with something like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController::Base

  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

  def index
    respond_with(@users = User.all)
  end

  def create
   @user = User.create(params[:user])
   respond_with(@user, :location => users_url)
  end
end
```

or even in your ajax query, for example, with jquery ($.ajax, $.get, $.post, $.getScript, etc) you can force the content type, something like:

```
$.getScript('ajax/test.js', function(data, textStatus){
  console.log(data); //data returned
  console.log(textStatus); //success
  console.log('Load was performed.');
```

});